# Let $0<a<b$. Then, for every positive integer $n$ show that $0<a^n<b^n$ and $0<a^{1/n}<b^{1/n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

The first one was really easy, I just used induction. But I am getting stumped on the second part, I know if I take the nth root of everything on $0<a^n<b^n$ I get $0<a<b$, I want to say that if this holds, then I can do the same by taking the $n$th root of $0<a<b$ and getting my desired result, can I do this? If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that works. Suppose that $0<a<b$ but $a^{1/n}\not<b^{1/n}$. Clearly they're not equal, so that means $0<b^{1/n}<a^{1/n}$. But applying your first result to this gives $0<b<a$, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

It follows also from the following reasoning:
$$\sqrt[n]{b}-\sqrt[n]a=\frac{b-a}{\sqrt[n]{b^{n-1}}+\sqrt[n]{b^{n-2}a}+...+\sqrt[n]{ba^{n-2}}+\sqrt[n]{a^{n-1}}}>0.$$

Comment: What formula is that? Haven’t seen it before,

Comment: Wait isn’t that the factor formula for a^n-b^n

Comment: @drfrankie Yes, I used $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+...+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}),$ which very easy to get after expanding. Try to get it.

Comment: Clever, haven’t seen it used that way before, I’ll have to remember this

Comment: @drfrankie It's a very useful folrmula.

Answer (score 0):

I am just using $e^{x}$ and $\log x$ are strictly increasing functions

$$0<a<b \implies \log a< \log b \implies \frac{1}{n} \log a < \frac{1}{n} \log b \implies \log a^{1/n} < \log b^{1/n} \implies a^{1/n} < b^{1/n} $$

infact you can use any constant $k \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ inplace of $1/n$ and argument still works

Comment: By the same logic I can just use the nth root of x as it is strictly increasing

Comment: @yes added . check now .